# Not being able to copy image from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to figure out how to copy an image from the "LargeTags" sheet to the "PrintLT" sheet.  Image one is what I am pulling from and image two is what I am trying to get.

However, what I get is image three.  the info in there properly without the images

I am using the code at the bottom to copy from LargeTags sheet to PrintLT sheet

Any help is appreciated.

Image One
[image]

Image Two
[image]

Image Three
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Price_Tags()
    Dim src As Worksheet    'the source worksheet
    Dim dest As Worksheet   'the destination worksheet
    Dim i As Long, Cols As Long
    Dim pasteRow As Long
    
Set src = Sheets("LargeTags")
Set dest = Sheets("PrintLT")

'prevent screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' number of columns to deal with
Cols = src.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To Cols Step 4
    ' where to paste to
    On Error Resume Next    'in case sheet2 is blank
    pasteRow = dest.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
        Select Case pasteRow
            Case 0, 1
                pasteRow = 2
            Case Else
                pasteRow = pasteRow + 2
        End Select
    On Error GoTo 0         're-instate error notification
    
    ' what to copy and where to paste
    With src
        .Cells(2, i).Resize(3, 4).Copy dest.Cells(pasteRow, 1)
    End With
    
    'format destination rows
    With dest.Rows(pasteRow).Cells(1)
        'row heights
        .RowHeight = 107.25                 'ROW 1
        .Offset(-1).RowHeight = 51.75      'the row above the item number
        .Offset(1).RowHeight = 42       'the price row
        .Offset(2).RowHeight = 19.5        'the description row
        .Offset(3).RowHeight = 15       'the row below the description
        'item font
        
        'center everything
        .Resize(3, 4).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Resize(3, 4).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
Next i
        
'format the column widths
With dest
    .Columns("A:D").ColumnWidth = 31.14
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

EDIT: I tried @DecimalTurn's suggestion. The top four headers are the correct size but after that, the 5th to 8th are still smaller.

Image 4
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy an image with VBA you can do a simple copy-paste with `.Copy` by making sure that the range you use includes the image.

In your case, it seems like the range where the images are located is missing from the range you are copying. Try changing :

`.Cells(2, i).Resize(3, 4).Copy dest.Cells(pasteRow, 1)`

to

`.Cells(1, i).Resize(4, 4).Copy dest.Cells(pasteRow-1, 1)`.

> REMARK: In cases where you aren't sure where the images are. It might be easier to copy images using the `Shapes` collection and the [Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.copy) on the shape objects associated with the images you want to copy.

EDIT:
I was not able to reproduce the image shrinking problem, but if all the shapes are of the same height and width, you could simply use this to restore their size after pasting:

```
Dim PictHeight As Double, PictWidth As Double
PictHeight = src.Shapes(1).Height
PictWidth = src.Shapes(1).Width

Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In dest.Shapes
    shp.Height = PictHeight
    shp.Width = PictWidth
Next
```

Comment: OK, technically it works however, as you can tell from image 4 in the initial question the image copied over doesn't have the right sizing.  The image should have a sizing of height of 1.29cm and a width of  5.81 cm

Comment: @scubadivingfool - What if you put the "format destination rows" section before the "what to copy and where to paste" section of your code?

Comment: the top four headers are the correct size but after that, the 5th to 8th are still smaller

Comment: @scubadivingfool I've edited the answer to provide a posible solution for the image shrinking issue.